# When do you unlock the Ponsonbys stores?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I've started to play GTA V, and I've been looking to unlock the Ponsonbys stores in order to get my characters all into suits. I've managed to locate one of the stores on Portola Drive, but I cannot enter. From what I understand you have to do a mission of some kind, but it's not entirely clear for me when this is.

The last missions I've completed are the ones that introduces Chop and has you repossess a motorbike, and I still have at least one mission available with Simeon (not quite sure how many). What do I still need to do to unlock these stores?

I would like a spoiler free answer, or at least answered in a way that I know it when I see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. By doing the mission [Friend Request](http://gta.wikia.com/Friend_Request) you unlock clothing stores in general. While you do not visit a Ponsonbys store during this mission you unlock them after finishing the mission.

This is the first mission you get from [Lester Crest](http://gta.wikia.com/Lester_Crest). This is the first mission you get as Michael after you encounter the Mexican businessman. After finishing that mission Michael has a phonecall with Lester, who invites you to come to his house. Finish that mission and you should unlock the various clothing stores in the game.

Answer (score 0):

You unlock the ability to enter Ponsonbys after you finish the mission titled "Meltdown".

In this mission Michael and Jimmy attend the premiere of the movie Meltdown. During the mission you go to Ponsonbys to look good for the premiere, after you complete the mission, you can go there any time.

Reference links:

[Ponsonbys](http://gta.wikia.com/Ponsonbys)

[Meltdown](http://gta.wikia.com/Meltdown_(GTA_V)) (beware of spoilers on this link)

Comment: So if I'm seeing this correctly by the template at the bottom of the page it's in the last half-dozen missions, right? Well, that's rather late to unlock something as basic as suits for your characters.

Comment: You unlock those two missions after meeting `Solomon Richards`, who you are introduced to by `Devin Weston`. The way they've structured their missions doesn't quite work exactly like that. If you do all side-quests prior to doing main story missions you'll find that you'll have these suits a lot longer than you think you will.

Comment: Yeah, it's extremly confusing as to how and when you unlock things. The wiki doesn't tell and there's no handy flowchart of things. Form what I can tell there's still an awful lot of missions ahead of be before I can unlock this.

Comment: -1. Meltdown is a mission that requires you to enter Ponsonbys but it does not unlocks the store or the suits. Also, Michael starts with a suit available on the the wardrobe in his mansion.